# HTML5 form pattern equivalent to PHP str_count_words

Tags: regex, html, forms, validation

In my PHP validation for forms I can use the following code in order to verify that the user has inserted more than three words in the text area:

```
if(str_word_count($comments) < 3) {
    $error_message .= 'The Message you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
```

What would be an equivalent pattern in html5?

I've tried this one, but it seems that with only one word it passes the validation (which it shouldn't do):

```
<textarea id="test" required="required" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}"></textarea>
```

Comment: You're just checking for the existence of 3 characters.. Consider including a *space* in your pattern: `[a-zA-Z0-9] {3,}`

Comment: Note that `pattern` is not supported on `textarea`: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-textarea-element

Comment: @gvee has the right idea, but \s+ instead of space character, and put the set and whitespace in parenthesis then the quantifier.

Comment: As Wesley Murch has said, it seems it's not supported on textarea, if you set your comment as an answer, I will accept it as valid.